# WPF Styling all elements using UIElement

Tags: wpf, styling, uielement

Here's something I want to do:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UIElement}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity"
                Value=".1" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

So that I can style any type (not just some final concrete UI type). I am not looking for best practices, its more of a question to ponder.

I noticed that WPF does not style any super class specified in `TargetType` (`UIElement`, `FrameworkElement`, etc etc). It styles only if the `TargetType` equates to the concrete UI class (`Button`, `Rectangle`).

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to define a base Style, you can however use BasedOn property.

```
<Style TargetType="FrameworkElement" x:Key="ElementBase">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource ElementBase}">
</Style>
```

It is a little bit more work, but maybe it helps.